# Aggregation query which returns other fields

Tags: mongodb

I have data which looks like this.

```
{ 
    "badgeId" : "ventura", 
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-22T21:26:40.382+0000"),
    "mistakes" : NumberInt(10)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "a4usNGibIu", 
    "badgeId" : "dog", 
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-21T21:26:40.382+0000"), 
    "mistakes" : NumberInt(10)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("580c77801d7723f3f7fe0e77"), 
    "badgeId" : "dog", 
    "date" : ISODate("2016-11-24T21:26:41.382+0000"), 
    "mistakes" : NumberInt(5)
}
```

**I need documents grouped by `badgeId` where the `mistakes` is smallest and the corresponding `date`**

I cannot use $min, $max, $first, $last on for the `date` in $group because I need the `date` from the row where `mistakes` is lowest.

I tried the following query where I am using `$min`, but it won't give the intended result as it will pick $min of the `date`

```
db.Badges.aggregate([
  {
    $match: otherMatchConditions
  },
  {
    $group: { 
      _id: '$badgeId',
      date: {
       $min: '$date'
      },
      mistakes: {
        $min: '$mistakes'
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may sort the results by `mistakes` and then take the corresponding `$first` of `mistakes` and `date`

```
[
  {$sort: {mistakes: 1}},
  {
    $group: { 
      _id: '$badgeId',
      date: {
       $first: '$date'
      },
      mistakes: {
        $first: '$mistakes'
      }
     }
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is right but as you see dates are invalid here.

**ISODate("2016-14-22T21:26:41.382+0000")** and **ISODate("2016-13-22T21:26:40.382+0000")**,

in both dates you can see months is 13 and 14 , which is not valid month. Below are right data after putting in mongodb.

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("580ca86c9a43fad551ba801f"),
    "badgeId" : "ventura",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-22T21:26:40.382Z"),
    "mistakes" : 10
   }
   {
    "_id" : "a4usNGibIu",
    "badgeId" : "dog",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-23T21:26:40.382Z"),
    "mistakes" : 10
  }
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("580c77801d7723f3f7fe0e77"),
    "badgeId" : "dog",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-24T21:26:40.382Z"),
    "mistakes" : 5
 }
```

When applied your query

```
db.getCollection('COLLECTION_NAME').aggregate([
  {
    $group: { 
      _id: '$badgeId',
      date: {
       $min: '$date'
      },
      mistakes: {
        $min: '$mistakes'
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I got the below result.

```
{
    "_id" : "dog",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-23T21:26:40.382Z"),
    "mistakes" : 5
}
{
    "_id" : "ventura",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-22T21:26:40.382Z"),
    "mistakes" : 10
}
```

Comment: sorry, it was hand code sample just for the question.

Comment: That's fine but it's work. as in my demo it's working good. If you have any concern or issue with finding data then please post your data so i can help you.